# Why do I get redirected even after I deleted window.location("url")

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, window.location

I created a login form and set the submit button to redirect to home.html with `window.location.replace("home.html")` and I also tried `window.location.href = "home.html"`

```
<button onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button>

functon signIn(){
    //Username input
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    //Password input
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    //Firebase function for signing in
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
}

//If user is signed in
auth.onAuthStateChanged(functon(user){
    if(user){
        window.location.href = "home.html"
    }
    else{
        alert("No credentials")
    }
})
```

However, I have deleted the redirect command and `home.html`. But anytime the user signs in, it redirects to a page that doesn't exist anymore. Even without the `window.location.replace()`

```
  <button onclick="signIn()"></button>


function signIn(){
     // The username input
    const userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    //The password input
    const userPass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
    //Firebase function for signing in
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            window.alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
        });
}
```

result:
[image: result o problem]

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your button so it won't submit the form. Or, even better (it allows enter to submit), do react on form submission but use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: When a user signs in, the onAuthStateChanged will redirect the user to home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const authObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(functon(user){
    if(user){
        window.location.href = "home.html"
    }
    else{
        alert("No credentials")
    }
})
```

You must unsubscribe from the Auth observer. You have a comment there `//If user is signed in` but actually this observer runs every time the Auth state changes I.e. user signs in or signs out.

```
function signIn(){
     // unsubscribing from Auth observer
     authObserver()
  
     // The username input
    const userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
}
```

When the `signIn` function is called, calling `authObserver()` will unsubscribe from Auth changes i.e. `onAuthStateChanged` will no longer redirect users itself.